# I want to place imageview in circular motion in xml

Tags: android

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.24">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background_tree"
            />
            <AbsoluteLayout
                android:id="@+id/llMapContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="390dp"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="44dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgLocation"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:layout_x="48px"
                    android:layout_y="440px"
                    android:src="@drawable/character_icon" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I want to place `ImageView` in the circles of the tree in my xml file . I tried using coordinates but it changes its positions with different screen size .

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i want place image diffrent images in different imageview bt their position will remaine constant in diffrent mobiles ,like 5.5, 5.2,4.7 inch screen

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:Create CircularimageView.class**

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {
        private int borderWidth;
        private int viewWidth;
        private int viewHeight;
        private Bitmap image;
        private Paint paint;
        private Paint paintBorder;
        private BitmapShader shader;

        public CircularImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setup();
        }

        public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setup();
        }

        public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setup();
        }

        private void setup() {
            // init paint
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            paintBorder = new Paint();
            setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
            paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
            this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
            this.setBorderWidth(2);
            paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
        }

        public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
            this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
            this.invalidate();
        }

        public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
            if (paintBorder != null)
                paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

            this.invalidate();
        }

        private void loadBitmap() {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

            if (bitmapDrawable != null)
                image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }

        @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // load the bitmap
            loadBitmap();

            // init shader
            if (image != null) {
                shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                paint.setShader(shader);
                int circleCenter = viewWidth / 2;

                // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
                // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
                // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
                canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
                canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter - 4.0f, paint);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

            viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
            viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }

        private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
            int result = 0;
            int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
            int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // We were told how big to be
                result = specSize;
            } else {
                // Measure the text
                result = viewWidth;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth) {
            int result = 0;
            int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
            int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // We were told how big to be
                result = specSize;
            } else {
                // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
                result = viewHeight;
            }

            return (result + 2);
        }
    }
```

**Step2:In layout.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.24">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <com.packagename.CircularImageView
             android:id="@+id/imgLocation"
             android:layout_width="65dp"
             android:layout_height="65dp"
             android:layout_x="48px"
             android:layout_y="440px"
             android:src="@drawable/character_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You get your answer @Nikhil ??